# How to align median, quartile information with box plot

Tags: matplotlib, seaborn

I'm creating a box plot and want the labels for median and quantiles.   I'm also specifying the order in which I want the plot to show.  The plot shows in the specific order, but the median and quantile information does not.

I've used this code on other box plots successfully, using different column names, but it will not work with these particular columns

```
a4_dims = (11.7, 8.27)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=a4_dims)
sns.boxplot(x='2017Seg', y='AbsYr1Dif', data=yr1, width=.7, showfliers=False,
           order=["<10","10-19","20-49","50-99","100-249","250+"])

medians = yr1.groupby(['2017Seg'])['AbsYr1Dif'].median().values
median_labels = [str(np.round(s, 2)) for s in medians]

pos = range(len(medians))
for tick,label in zip(pos,ax.get_xticklabels()):
    ax.text(pos[tick], medians[tick] + 0.02, median_labels[tick], 
            horizontalalignment='center', size='small', color='w', weight='semibold')

    upperquart = yr1.groupby(['2017Seg'])['AbsYr1Dif'].quantile(.75).values
upperquart_labels = [str(np.round(s, 2)) for s in upperquart]

pos = range(len(upperquart))
for tick,label in zip(pos,ax.get_xticklabels()):
    ax.text(pos[tick], upperquart[tick] + 0.02, upperquart_labels[tick], 
            horizontalalignment='left', size='small', color='b', weight='semibold')

lowerquart = yr1.groupby(['2017Seg'])['AbsYr1Dif'].quantile(.25).values
lowerquart_labels = [str(np.round(s, 2)) for s in lowerquart]

pos = range(len(lowerquart))
for tick,label in zip(pos,ax.get_xticklabels()):
    ax.text(pos[tick], lowerquart[tick] - 0.05, lowerquart_labels[tick], 
            horizontalalignment='right', size='small', color='b', weight='semibold')
```

could not use snip tool.

The order in which the median and quantile information appear is the natural sort order before using sort on the boxplot definition

Sample of data that is not working:

[image: Sample of data not working]

Sample of data that is working:

[image: Sample Data that previously worked]

Boxplot not working - median / quantile out of order

[image: Boxplot not working - median / quantile out of order]

Comment: Can you post a sample of the data `yr1`? And maybe a sample of data that has worked before.

Comment: Not working    
 ID 2017Seg AbsYr1Dif AbsYr2Dif
0 gre 10-19 0.018 0.168715715
1 jks 10-19 0.027 0.119801383
2 hfe <10 0.064 0.4282475
3 skf 10-19 0.099 0.205606116
4 jje 10-19 0.014 0.558228333
    
    
Worked before    
ID PredictiveScore ScoreSeg  
bbd 1.2 7-8  
cfd 0.549 6-6  
gre 0.714 6-6  
tub 1.016 1-3  
sjk 0.377 4-5  
klk 0.813 6-6

Comment: Not sure if that is legible.  How can I post a sample set from Excel

Comment: Thanks, it'd be better if you just edited your question and post it there :)

Comment: @HS-Nebula - updated.